# problem with jquery tablesorter pager

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am trying to use the tablesorter pager plugin to page my list.  I have the following code for the pager -

```
<img src="../../Content/images/first.png" class="first" />
<img src="../../Content/images/prev.png" class="prev" />
<input type="text" class="pagedisplay" />
<img src="../../Content/images/next.png" class="next" />
<img src="../../Content/images/last.png" class="last" />
<select class="pagesize" />
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tblmyTableID")
.tablesorter({ widthFixed: true })
.tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });
});
</script>
```

From the samples I've seen, this looks to be correct, but I am getting the following error whenever I click on one of the navigation buttons -

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object
```

I have ensure that the table name is the same as what is defined in the jquery function.  Here are the libraries I am using -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
```

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error?  Could it be an incompatibility with the version of jquery?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Do you try to sort an empty table? I've seen this error in this situation.

Comment: No, there is data in the table.

Comment: Do your table headers have `<td></td>` tags instead of `<th></th>`. That caused me some problems a few days ago. Also Does it work without the pager?

Comment: I did have the table headings set as <th>, but I changed them to <td> and still the same problem.